# Get Values From a Specific Column Into a Dropdown

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Want to ask if there's a quick way, an automated or using formulas for this scenario.

So I have "config" sheet, and each columns is a list used for a specific dropdown.
config!A:A = clientA
config!B:B = clientB

In a "summary" sheet, I need to add a dropdown in column C depending on the column A

For example summary!A2 contains "client A" so the dropdown in summary!C2 will show the list of clientA
And summary!A3 contains "client B" so the dropdown in summary!C3 will show the list of clientB

What I currently do is named the range each in the "config" then in "summary" I put the Data Validation for the specific name.

I was wondering if there's a custom formula that I can put in the Data Validation for Column C that depends on the value in column A. The only challenge is there are spaces so in the Named Range I remove the space. And since it depends on the column, the row number is moving.

Looking for a formula since I am avoiding App Script for this specific file. Thanks

Hopefully someone could help me on this.

Thanks much.

You are all awesome!

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is set an Auxiliary sheet (or extra columns far in "Summary"). You can set Summary!C2 the next Data Validation:

> =Auxiliary!A1:1

Open the settings of that data validation and make sure there are no anchors (no $, for example A$1). If there is some, delete them

Close it and then copy and paste special - Data Validation only to the rest of the cells
[image]

This way C2 will be associated with row 2 from Auxiliary, C3 with row 3 and so on

Then, you can go to Auxiliary and set a formula in each row to filter the values according to B2, B3 (or however you identify the client... (a Query, or Filter) --> You'll probably need to transpose the information, so the list becomes a row

With that done, each data validation will depend now on the value of that row

---

Re-reading your example, you can do the same but instead of filter you can transpose the entire Config sheet and you'll have a row per client
......

You have an example here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jF5XoBkQll5tHEjADg508NMznmbuB43tyWv5R2S1mM8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi, Thanks I tried this one. It was working, but I am stuck on the part where it needs to show as a dropdown for the cells in Column C.

Comment: Hello @SBBmaster, could you share a copy of what you've done so far and in which stage you're stuck? Thanks!

Comment: Sharing the sample file I am currently working on https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cJ_EzqdupLVtsGPE9h9tmqbZ25bgYmi5X92D8OZkE2o/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Since the validation is in a Sheet with the name of the client, on its first row, I've made a formula in Summary!N:N that brings that information with INDIRECT and set validation to that same row in each case. Try creating a Customer D sheet and putting some values, or add more rows with that same criteria!

Comment: Thanks the dropdown works when I pull it down. But is there a way that it's not within the summary sheet? Can be pulling from the Config sheet instead since the other columns are filled up and columns of each client is growing too.

Comment: Hey @martin actually got it worked. Thanks so much. That's a big help. 